# Symfony3 проблема с enum (Postgresql types)

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony3, doctrine2

Все привет. Ребята, вопрос такой, каким способом создаете enum поля с помощью миграций в Symfony? Делаю [вот так ВТОРОЙ ОТВЕТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750724/what-do-you-use-instead-of-enum-in-doctrine2) но при дальнейших `doctrine:migrations:diff` создаются лишние файлы миграций с `$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user_field ALTER "enum_field" DROP NOT NULL');`

Как с этим быть или возможно есть способ лучше?! Возможно стоит прислушаться и использовать `smallint`? Не радует то, что пропадает целостность данных в бд. Можно записать любое число к примеру напрямую.

Заранее спасибо!